# Dynamic Array Allocation in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

the code is working but there is an error. Return array 
using return by reference this function-> void alloc(int **array, int size).What do you think of this error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void memoryys(int **array, int size);
int main()
{
    int i;
    int in;
    int *a1;

    printf("please number of elements  ");
    scanf("%d",in);
    alloc(&a1,in);

    for(i=0;i<in;i++){
       scanf("d ",&a1[i]);
    }
    free(a1);

    return 0;
}

void alloc(int **array, int size){
   int i;
   *array = (int *) malloc(size*sizeof(int));
   if (*array == NULL){
      printf("Error\n");
      exit(-1);
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` in C.

Comment: `scanf("d ",&a1[i]);` --> `scanf("%d", &a1[i]);`

Comment: thanks,for your answer...

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying the address of the variable in scanf

```
scanf("%d",input1);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d",&input1);
```

In general it is better to use fgets to read from the keyboard to have a certain control over what the user enters. Then use sscanf to convert the value to your desired type.

```
char line[128];
if (fgets(line,sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL)
{
  if (sscanf(line,"%d", &n) == 1)
  {
    do something useful
  }
  else
  {
    puts("invalid input");
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks,for your answer...

Comment: @HUDUT - if the answer was helpful to you, up click it.  If it was not, ask a question, or leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

With an array in C you are really just allocating a contiguous block of space for a particular data type, `int` in this case.

***On the stack***, an array of `int` is created like this:
`int array[2][6];`//2x6 for example, 2 arrays of 6 integers each (or 2 *rows*, each with 6 *columns*)
***Conceptually***, it would perhaps look like rows and columns:

```
       0   1   2   3   4   5
0    |int|int|int|int|int|int|
1    |int|int|int|int|int|int|
```

***Actually***, in memory, it is just a contiguous block of space sufficient for 12 `int`:

```
|int|int|int|int|int|int|int|int|int|int|int|int|
```

The index operator: `[]` provides a visually simple way to access the elements, where for example,
array[1][3] would represent the 10th element

***For an array created on the heap***:

```
int **array=0;
```

First, create the pointers necessary (represented by the [2])

```
array = malloc(sizeof(int *) * 2); //provide two pointers
```

giving you pointers array[0] & array[1]

Now you can allocate memory for each of these pointers: (represented by the [6])

```
array[0] = malloc(sizeof(int)*6); //space for 6 ints   
array[1] = malloc(sizeof(int)*6); //space for 6 ints
```

the two *row* pointers point to these locations:

```
    |int|int|int|int|int|int|int|int|int|int|int|int|  
    ^ array[0]              ^ array[1]
```

Giving you a representation of a 2D array: `array[2][6];`.

Do not forget to free everything when finished, for each malloc, there should be one free:

```
free(array[0]);    
free(array[1]);
free(array);
```